# Per-site ASP setting for "caching properties"

Tags: iis

In IIS GUI, the **ASP\Caching Properties** settings are only available on a per server basis.  On a per site level, they are greyed out, as per the image below.

[image: Per-site caching]

However, I have noticed that some of our sites settings were not changing when the global (server level) settings were changed.  When I looked into it, I saw that the sites had individual settings set within the **applicationhost.config** under a **location** tag.

```
<location path="sitename">
        <system.webServer>
            <asp errorsToNTLog="true" logErrorRequests="true" enableParentPaths="true" scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true" bufferingOn="true">
                <session allowSessionState="true" />
                <cache scriptFileCacheSize="25" />  <-------- THIS
            </asp>
```

My question is around whether this is supported or indeed actually works?  Given the UI does not allow you to do this, what is the impact of doing this on a per-site level?